# Variable repeating depending on loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm searching a string into 2 websites.

Each website have the same string, now the main problem is:

```
s = "name:'(.*)',"

WebType = re.findall(s, html1)   

for name in WebType:    
    if 'RoundCube' or 'SquirrelMail' in name:    
        print host + "--> " + name
```

So basically, I think that the results repeat depending on loop results.

The results are:

```
https://website1.com--> Roundcube
https://website1.com--> SquirrelMail

https://website2.com--> Roundcube
https://website2.com--> SquirrelMail
```

How can I make the results to be:

```
https://website1.com--> RoundCube, SquirrelMail
https://website2.com--> Roundcube, SquirrelMail
```

Comment: Is all of this code within a loop that iterates over the `hosts`? You could just do `WebType = set(re.findall(s, html1))` if you want to remove duplicates.

Comment: Unfortunately is not working..

Answer (score 0):

dursk's solution above should have worked. However, a longer solution is:

```
s = "name:'(.*)',"
WebType = re.findall(s, html1)
results = []
for name in WebType:
    if 'RoundCube' or 'SquirrelMail' in name:
        results.append(name)
print host + "--> " + ', '.join(results)
```

Comment: `http://website1.com-->Roundcube
https://website1.com--> Roundcube,SquirrelMail
http://website2.com-->Roundcube
https://website2.com--> Roundcube,SquirrelMail`

This one won't work too...

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a space between each match. I have updated my answer accordingly. Does this work for you now?

Comment: It's not about space, it's about the array, it must contain unique details when I get the name :D

Comment: Basically HOST is repeating as much as values contain name, so if name contains 3, host will repeat 3 times, if name contains 2, host will repeat 2 times and so on. I want that host must repeat only once.

Comment: pythy, the example I gave above prints HOST only once, but results multiple times. Isn't that what you expect or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Exactly, as I said I want HOST once with name:


site.com -> name1, name2
site2.com -> name1, name2
But your code still don't work. ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import random 
hosts = ['https://website1.com', 'https://website2.com']
WebList = ['RoundCube', 'SquirrelMail'] + ['webtype_{}'.format(x) for x in range(2)]
WebType = WebList[random.randint(0, len(WebList)):]
name_list = ['RoundCube', 'SquirrelMail']

for host in hosts:
    name = filter(set(WebType).__contains__, name_list)
    if len(name):
        print host + "--> " + str(name).lstrip('[').rstrip(']').replace('\'', '')
```

I created `WebList` for testing purposes.
In your code, you will not need to import `random` unless you want to test what's here.

It outputs:

```
https://website1.com--> RoundCube, SquirrelMail
https://website2.com--> RoundCube, SquirrelMail
```

It also outputs:

```
https://website1.com--> SquirrelMail
https://website2.com--> SquirrelMail
```

You might need to adjust it to your needs.